# Corda V1.0 Notary clusters config issue with Gradle

Tags: corda

I use below config to construct Notary Cluster and launch them. I used like this kind script into V14 version that's ok. but in V1 pop up that error. please help me to check.

task deployNodesRAFT(type: net.corda.plugins.Cordform, dependsOn: ['jar']) {

```
directory "./build/nodes"
networkMap "C=CH,L=Zurich,O=NotaryService0"

node {
    name "C=CH,L=Zurich,O=NotaryService0"
    advertisedServices = ["corda.notary.validating.raft|C=CH,L=Zurich,O=Raft,CN=corda.notary.validating.raft"]
    p2pPort 10002
    rpcPort 10003
    notaryNodePort 10001
    cordapps = []
}
node {
    name "C=CH,L=Zurich,O=NotaryService1"
    advertisedServices = ["corda.notary.validating.raft|C=CH,L=Zurich,O=Raft,CN=corda.notary.validating.raft"]
    p2pPort 10091
    rpcPort 10092
    cordapps = []
    notaryNodePort 10093
    notaryClusterAddresses = ["localhost:10001"]
}
node {
    name "C=CH,L=Zurich,O=NotaryService2"
    advertisedServices = ["corda.notary.validating.raft|C=CH,L=Zurich,O=Raft,CN=corda.notary.validating.raft"]
    p2pPort 10094
    rpcPort 10095
    cordapps = []
    notaryNodePort 10096
    notaryClusterAddresses = ["localhost:10001"]
}
```

log:
[ERROR] 2017-10-17T05:42:31,180Z [main] identity.PersistentIdentityService.verifyAndRegisterIdentity - name constraints check failed
[ERROR] 2017-10-17T05:42:31,181Z [main] identity.PersistentIdentityService.verifyAndRegisterIdentity - Path = 
[ERROR] 2017-10-17T05:42:31,181Z [main] identity.PersistentIdentityService.verifyAndRegisterIdentity - CN=Corda Node Root CA,O=R3,OU=corda,L=London,C=UK
[ERROR] 2017-10-17T05:42:31,182Z [main] identity.PersistentIdentityService.verifyAndRegisterIdentity - CN=Corda Node Intermediate CA,O=R3,OU=corda,L=London,C=UK
[ERROR] 2017-10-17T05:42:31,184Z [main] identity.PersistentIdentityService.verifyAndRegisterIdentity - C=CH,L=Zurich,O=NotaryService0,CN=Corda Client CA Certificate
[ERROR] 2017-10-17T05:42:31,185Z [main] identity.PersistentIdentityService.verifyAndRegisterIdentity - C=CH,L=Zurich,O=Raft,CN=corda.notary.validating.raft
[ERROR] 2017-10-17T05:42:31,189Z [main] internal.Node.run - Exception during node startup
rx.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException: name constraints check failed
    at rx.internal.util.InternalObservableUtils$ErrorNotImplementedAction.call(InternalObservableUtils.java:386) ~[rxjava-1.2.4.jar:1.2.4]
    at rx.internal.util.InternalObservableUtils$ErrorNotImplementedAction.call(InternalObservableUtils.java:383) ~[rxjava-1.2.4.jar:1.2.4]
    at rx.internal.util.ActionSubscriber.onError(ActionSubscriber.java:44) ~[rxjava-1.2.4.jar:1.2.4]
    at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber._onError(SafeSubscriber.java:153) ~[rxjava-1.2.4.jar:1.2.4]
    at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber.onError(SafeSubscriber.java:115) ~[rxjava-1.2.4.jar:1.2.4]
    at rx.exceptions.Exceptions.throwOrReport(Exceptions.java:216) ~[rxjava-1.2.4.jar:1.2.4]
    at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber.onNext(SafeSubscriber.java:139) ~[rxjava-1.2.4.jar:1.2.4]
    at rx.observers.Subscribers$5.onNext(Subscribers.java:235) ~[rxjava-1.2.4.jar:1.2.4]
    at net.corda.node.utilities.DatabaseTransactionWrappingSubscriber$onNext$1.invoke(CordaPersistence.kt:159) ~[corda-node-1.0.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.utilities.DatabaseTransactionWrappingSubscriber$onNext$1.invoke(CordaPersistence.kt:143) ~[corda-node-1.0.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.utilities.DatabaseTransactionWrappingSubscriber$forEachSubscriberWithDbTx$1.invoke(CordaPersistence.kt:150) ~[corda-node-1.0.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.utilities.DatabaseTransactionWrappingSubscriber$forEachSubscriberWithDbTx$1.invoke(CordaPersistence.kt:143) ~[corda-node-1.0.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.utilities.CordaPersistence.inTopLevelTransaction(CordaPersistence.kt:84) ~[corda-node-1.0.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.utilities.CordaPersistence.transaction(CordaPersistence.kt:75) ~[corda-node-1.0.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.utilities.CordaPersistence.transaction(CordaPersistence.kt:65) ~[corda-node-1.0.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.utilities.DatabaseTransactionWrappingSubscriber.forEachSubscriberWithDbTx(CordaPersistence.kt:148) ~[corda-node-1.0.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.utilities.DatabaseTransactionWrappingSubscriber.onNext(CordaPersistence.kt:159) ~[corda-node-1.0.0.jar:?]
    at rx.subjects.PublishSubject$PublishSubjectProducer.onNext(PublishSubject.java:304) ~[rxjava-1.2.4.jar:1.2.4]
    at rx.subjects.PublishSubject$PublishSubjectState.onNext(PublishSubject.java:219) ~[rxjava-1.2.4.jar:1.2.4]
    at rx.subjects.PublishSubject.onNext(PublishSubject.java:72) ~[rxjava-1.2.4.jar:1.2.4]
    at rx.internal.util.ObserverSubscriber.onNext(ObserverSubscriber.java:34) ~[rxjava-1.2.4.jar:1.2.4]
    at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber.onNext(SafeSubscriber.java:134) ~[rxjava-1.2.4.jar:1.2.4]
    at rx.observers.Subscribers$5.onNext(Subscribers.java:235) ~[rxjava-1.2.4.jar:1.2.4]
    at rx.subjects.UnicastSubject$State.replay(UnicastSubject.java:295) ~[rxjava-1.2.4.jar:1.2.4]
    at rx.subjects.UnicastSubject$State.request(UnicastSubject.java:237) ~[rxjava-1.2.4.jar:1.2.4]
    at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:209) ~[rxjava-1.2.4.jar:1.2.4]
    at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:205) ~[rxjava-1.2.4.jar:1.2.4]
    at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:205) ~[rxjava-1.2.4.jar:1.2.4]
    at rx.subjects.UnicastSubject$State.call(UnicastSubject.java:252) ~[rxjava-1.2.4.jar:1.2.4]
    at rx.subjects.UnicastSubject$State.call(UnicastSubject.java:115) ~[rxjava-1.2.4.jar:1.2.4]
    at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10142) ~[rxjava-1.2.4.jar:1.2.4]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDelaySubscriptionOther$1.onCompleted(OnSubscribeDelaySubscriptionOther.java:74) ~[rxjava-1.2.4.jar:1.2.4]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDelaySubscriptionOther$1.onNext(OnSubscribeDelaySubscriptionOther.java:53) ~[rxjava-1.2.4.jar:1.2.4]
    at rx.internal.producers.SingleProducer.request(SingleProducer.java:65) ~[rxjava-1.2.4.jar:1.2.4]
    at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:209) ~[rxjava-1.2.4.jar:1.2.4]
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorSingle$ParentSubscriber.onCompleted(OperatorSingle.java:110) ~[rxjava-1.2.4.jar:1.2.4]
    at rx.internal.operators.OperatorTake$1.onNext(OperatorTake.java:80) ~[rxjava-1.2.4.jar:1.2.4]
    at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeFilter$FilterSubscriber.onNext(OnSubscribeFilter.java:76) ~[rxjava-1.2.4.jar:1.2.4]
    at rx.subjects.PublishSubject$PublishSubjectProducer.onNext(PublishSubject.java:304) ~[rxjava-1.2.4.jar:1.2.4]
    at rx.subjects.PublishSubject$PublishSubjectState.onNext(PublishSubject.java:219) ~[rxjava-1.2.4.jar:1.2.4]
    at rx.subjects.PublishSubject.onNext(PublishSubject.java:72) ~[rxjava-1.2.4.jar:1.2.4]
    at rx.observers.SerializedObserver.onNext(SerializedObserver.java:91) ~[rxjava-1.2.4.jar:1.2.4]
    at rx.subjects.SerializedSubject.onNext(SerializedSubject.java:67) ~[rxjava-1.2.4.jar:1.2.4]
    at net.corda.node.utilities.DatabaseTransaction.close(DatabaseTransactionManager.kt:60) ~[corda-node-1.0.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.utilities.CordaPersistence.inTopLevelTransaction(CordaPersistence.kt:100) ~[corda-node-1.0.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.utilities.CordaPersistence.transaction(CordaPersistence.kt:75) ~[corda-node-1.0.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.utilities.CordaPersistence.transaction(CordaPersistence.kt:65) ~[corda-node-1.0.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.services.network.PersistentNetworkMapCache.addNode(PersistentNetworkMapCache.kt:163) ~[corda-node-1.0.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode.registerWithNetworkMapIfConfigured(AbstractNode.kt:511) ~[corda-node-1.0.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.internal.AbstractNode.start(AbstractNode.kt:220) ~[corda-node-1.0.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.internal.Node.start(Node.kt:312) ~[corda-node-1.0.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.internal.NodeStartup.startNode(NodeStartup.kt:95) ~[corda-node-1.0.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.internal.NodeStartup.run(NodeStartup.kt:74) [corda-node-1.0.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.Corda.main(Corda.kt:11) [corda-node-1.0.0.jar:?]
Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: name constraints check failed

Comment: I think for this part to generate CordX500Name of Notary clusters that different other sample. as "C=CH,L=Zurich,O=NotaryService0" , it's not (O,L,C)

Comment: just check, I missed a way to generate distributedService.jks , so in the future do you have some way to involve it into internal without our own implement?

Answer (score 0):

As you mention in your second comment, the node configs are fine, but you haven't generated the `distributedService` certificate.

To generate this certificate automatically, take a look at the Gradle task defined here, that creates a cluster of RAFT notaries for you: https://github.com/corda/corda/blob/release-V1/samples/notary-demo/src/main/kotlin/net/corda/notarydemo/RaftNotaryCordform.kt. The shared certificate is generated on line 65.

Comment: Hi joel, thank you for help.  for this> java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: class configured for KeyPairGenerator (provider: BC) cannot be found.
net.i2p.crypto.eddsa.KeyPairGenerator    how to fix this error with build.

Comment: dependencies {
        classpath "net.i2p.crypto:eddsa:$eddsa_version" // Needed for ServiceIdentityGenerator in the build environment.
    } ok I got it

Comment: by the way, why for notary cluster nodes name have been change to  (O,L,C) , Corda default is(C,L,O)

Comment: Good stuff. I believe the name fields can appear in any order you like.

Comment: Hi Joel, if used template project for V3.1 corda Notary sample project, it will didn't generate contract state jar file  into its fold cordapp. do you have any idea for it?

Comment: Can you raise this as a separate question, please?